# Calculate mean and convert data table javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the data like example below. First column is id, second is v1, third is v2.

data

```
var v1Func = d3.random.normal(100, 15)
 var v2Func = d3.random.normal(200, 30)
 

   var sample = {
           id: [],
           v1: [],
           v2: []

        }

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         sample.id.push(i+1);
         sample.v1.push(v1Func());
         sample.v2.push(v2Func()); 
        }
```

My question is how to calculate the mean of column v1 and v2, then convert the data table like this:

```
name  mean
v1     *
v2     *
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for but the following gets you an object with the data as you want it:

```js
var v1Func = d3.random.normal(100, 15)
 var v2Func = d3.random.normal(200, 30)


   var sample = {
           id: [],
           v1: [],
           v2: [],

        }

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         sample.id.push(i+1);
         sample.v1.push(v1Func());
         sample.v2.push(v2Func()); 
        }

var totalv1 = 0;
var totalv2 = 0;
for (var i =0; i < sample.v1.length; i++) {
    totalv1 += sample.v1[i];
    totalv2 += sample.v2[i];
}

var averagev1 = totalv1/sample.v1.length;
var averagev2 = totalv2/sample.v2.length;

var dataTable = [
    {
        name: "v1",
        mean: averagev1
    },
    {
        name: "v2",
        mean: averagev2
    }
];
```

See [this snippet.](http://jsfiddle.net/e7d6d50d/)

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thanks so much!